# Pass Value in handleChange Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

In all the examples that I saw online, only the event was being passed into the handleChange and value was being used automatically. However, I get an error that value is not found. How can I use value in the handleChange? I am trying to validate the form using Formik here.

```
export default function MyPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<Response>(USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    User({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<Response>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
          setIsRemoved(true);
        }
      })  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues:{ email: '' },
    onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        },
       validationSchema:schema
    })

    const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
      if (name!== null) && (value!==null){
      const {name,value} = event.target;
      formik.setFieldValue(name,value);
      }
     }

  return (
    <div>
              <Form
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(formik.values.email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ''}
                    error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={formik.values.email}
                    //onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !formik.values.email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On this line:

```
const {name,value} = event.target;
```

I also get this error even though I am already checking this with an if statement:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget | null'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Your event is iniatilised as `e` but used as `event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the values that are not assigned yet. First, declare them then try to access them. Also, you are using `event.target` but you need to use `e.target` instead as you have declared event like:

```
 const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
```

So, the code inside the `handleChange()` function needs to be updated like:

```
 const { name,value } = e.target;
 if (name && value){
    formik.setFieldValue(name, value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your handleChange, you use (e) as a parameter but then you reference event.target. Rename your parameter to (event).

```
handleChange= (event) => {
    const {name,value} = event.target;
    ...
}
```